# Como puxar dados do BD para Tabela ? (REACTJS + NODEJS + API)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, table

Quero criar uma tabela (essa tabela já esta criada no meu frontend - apenas html e bootstrap) e que nela venha informações do meu banco de dados, ou seja, das pessoas cadastradas no meu banco, gostaria que estivessem nessa tabela. Como fazer isso ?

meu backend : https://github.com/VeronicaEms/apiRest
meu frontend : https://github.com/VeronicaEms/reactjsFront

Answer (score 1):

boa tarde.

Apesar de já estarmos nos falando no discord sugiro:

1º API rodando, confira as portas onde está rodando sua api.

2º Use alguma ferramenta para testar requisições como por ex: Insomnia.

3° Verifique o permissionamento, se o acesso ao token está certo se salvou ele no seu local storage para conferir com o que está no banco.

Estou verificando seu código e farei um PR com alguns ajustes se eu conseguir reproduzir as falhas.

Abçs!